# What would be "inquetht"?

Tags: meaning, orthography

> "I thay, misther," expostulat the Hebrew, "shut that bocth. Thmellth like a blooming inquetht."

From "[Percival Bland's Proxy](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks05/0500391h.html)" by R. Austin Freeman. I can decipher it as

> "I say, Mister," expostulate the Hebrew, "shut that box. Smells like a blooming **inquetht**."

but what would be "inquetht"?

Comment: Given that every single other `th` in that quote has been substituted for an `s`, it would be an ***inquest***. No, I have no idea what an inquest smells like, other than trouble. I'll leave it to you to interpret in context.

Comment: I thuthpect that itth thomething dithpicable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too narrow (it deals with one author's particular phonetic respelling of a term). Questions are supposed to be applicable to the general public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clearly "inquest" spoken with a lisp. Inquest actually means

> a judicial inquiry to ascertain the facts relating to an incident. (usually in the context of something undesirable like a violent or unexpected death)

so I would actually argue that its use in this line is slightly inaccurate: it would more accurately be "Thmellth like a blooming autopthy."